# Is there any solution for this error while installing odoo17

Tags: python, odoo

I want to install requirement for odoo 17 i run this command
pip install -r requirements.txt
put get this error .... i already install visual studio 2022
what should i install to solve this error
i install python 10

```
Using cached zope.event-5.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Using cached zope.interface-6.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (204 kB)
Using cached soupsieve-2.5-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: libsass
  Building wheel for libsass (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      You probably need Visual Studio 2015 (14.0) or higher
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying pysassc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying sass.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying sassc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      copying sasstests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sassutils
      copying sassutils\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sassutils
      copying sassutils\distutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sassutils
      copying sassutils\wsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sassutils
      copying sassutils\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sassutils
      copying sassutils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\sassutils
      running build_ext
      building '_sass' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-buil
d-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for libsass
  Running setup.py clean for libsass
Failed to build libsass
ERROR: Could not build wheels for libsass, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: Hello @heba Can you try with a specific version libsass==0.20.1?

Comment: which command should i run

Comment: Hello Heba pip3 install libsass==0.20.1

Comment: Package conflicts are the cause of this; to resolve it, configure Odoo using a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing wheel before installing requirements.txt

> pip install --upgrade wheel

If the above solution won't work then try installing prophet library by running the below command then install requirements.txt:

> python -m pip install prophet

Hope this will help :)